# Grading system in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a separate table for storing grading systems (can be more than one for various courses), and then the tutor should choose the relevant grading system as drop-down generated from the created grading system after posting the students results, please help with MYSQL database way.

Comment: One table for all courses.  There are hundreds of examples online.

Answer (score -2):

Can you be briefer with the design you want for the grading system?
Normally you can use one table for all your courses and insert grades as selected from the dropdown alongside respective courses.
And if you want to keep student-specific records, keep a separate student table and relate it to the course table with a foreign key.